# Getting the selected drop down value in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, drop-down-menu

I want to get the selected value from the drop down list to a variable. I am loading the drop down list values from the database initially. Inside my view file,

```
           <select name="trackerid" style="height:30px; width:140px";>
           <?php foreach ($imei as $row):
            { 

                echo "<option value=\"trackerid\">" . $row['imie'] . "</option>";

           } 
           endforeach; ?>
           </select>
```

With the above code, I was able to load the imei numbers from database. When I click the submit button, I want to send the selected imei to the database. In my controller file,

```
          $NewConfArray["IMIE"] = $this->input->post("trackerid");
```

But when I write a simple var_dump to test, it returns bool(false).

```
         var_dump(  $NewConfArray["IMIE"]);
```

I want to get the selected imei from view  file. How to get it? Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: "trackerid" is your name of the select box and all values of your select ? `echo "<option value=\". $row['imie'] .\">" . $row['imie'] . "</option>";`

Comment: @Bira Thank you. As you all have kindly mentioned, I haven't included "option value" in my html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have not put value in your option try this

```
echo "<option value='".$row['imie']."'>" . $row['imie'] . "</option>";
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, whenn you add some explaination to your intension.

Comment: @reporter thanks for your suggestions. i have mentioned the problem. if you have some suggestions update my answer. i will appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give imei number in value of select also -

```
<select name="trackerid" style="height:30px; width:140px";>
           <?php foreach ($imei as $row):
            { 
               $imei_number = $row['imie'];

                echo "<option value='$imei_number'>" . $imei_number . "</option>";

           } 
           endforeach; ?>
           </select>
```